# How to install and configure Qt on uClinux for ARM7TDMI-S?

Tags: qt, uclinux

First I installed, configured and compiled Qt 5.3.2 on Linux (Debian). My simple Qt-program was compiled and ran without any problems on Linux.

But it didn't work on uClinux for a processor lpc2478.

So I installed QtEmbedded-linux-4.4.0 and did the next configuration:

```
./configure -embedded ARM7TDMI-S -xplatform qws/linux-arm-g++ -no-webkit -no-qt3support -release
```

and then I did `make` and `make install`.

After that my program didn't run on uClinux arm. What did I wrong? Maybe I used a wrong compilator?

Comment: Mixing 5.3.2 and 4.4.0? Either way, can you show your test program? What exactly do you mean by your program did not run?

Comment: Yes, here it is, the test source code that I try to compile and run (it just outputs the numbers from 0 to 99):

#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 100) {
        qDebug()<<QString::number(i++);
    }
    return a.exec();
}

I execute next commands:
'/usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.4.0-arm/bin/qmake test.pro'
and 'make'. When I run this program on my ARM I get next error:
BINFMT_FLAT: bad header magic
ELFa: not found

Comment: Generated Makefile uses compilators
CC = arm-linux-gcc
CXX = arm-linux-g++
Maybe for ARM7TDMI-S thew won't work?